# How do I stop Visual Studio 2013 from removing the spaces I've added to line code up?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, coding-style

VS's autoformat settings appear to remove the spaces I add to line things up visually.  So, if I have:

```
var CANVAS_MARGIN            = 10;
    CENTROID_INTERNAL_RADIUS = 10,
    FLUX_CAP_MFAD            = 7,
```

Then, when I press enter, it strips the spaces so that I wind up with:

```
var CANVAS_MARGIN = 10;
    CENTROID_RADIUS = 10,
    FLUX_CAP_MFAD = 7,
```

I've looked through the JavaScript and General settings for formatting under "Editor" preferences, but can't seem to find a setting to alter this.

Many thanks,
Dave

Comment: Are you using spaces or tabs?

Comment: Don't waste your time trying to line this up. Depending on the font you use; tab vs spaces; or editor settings these will never be consistent. Also you have a semi-colon on the first line.

Comment: Spaces.  The semicolon is a typo in my example. "Don't do that" doesn't answer the question.  I've maintained code like that by hand for decades, would prefer my editor doesn't mess it up, that's all.